# Creating HTML Forms from PHP Arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to make a form in html that would create radio options bases upon the specified array in PHP.

Code:

```
<form name="form" action="Test.php" method="get">
<?php
//Creates the Array
$radioButtonArray = array("cat", "dog", "sheep", "moose");

//Length of the Array
$count = count($radioButtonArray);

//Runs for each index.
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++)
//Creates a radio button with the specified length
echo "<input=\"radio\" name=\"Animal\" value=\"{$radioButtonArray[$x]}\">{$radioButtonArray[$x]}        <br>";
?>
</form>
```

As you can see firstly I  open the form tag inside of HTML. Then I create a array with animals names and run a loop through each array index. During each loop it should create a new radio button and then make a new line as directed by the echo.

The issue is that when I run the file the output should be for example:

```
(RADIO BUTTON HERE) cat
(RADIO BUTTON HERE) dog
(RADIO BUTTON HERE) sheep
(RADIO BUTTON HERE) moose
```

Instead I get:

```
cat
dog
sheep
moose
```

I know that it is reading the echo line so the error would have to be located on that line. I am very new to PHP and decently familiar with HTML so a simple but detailed explanation of what I did wrong or what I should do would be very greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**How to Fix:**

I did not correctly enter the format for declaring a input.

```
//Change This
echo "<input=\"radio\" name=\"Animal\" value=\"{$radioButtonArray[$x]}\">{$radioButtonArray[$x]}<br>";

//To This
 echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Animal\" value=\"{$radioButtonArray[$x]}\">{$radioButtonArray[$x]}<br>";
```

Comment: That gives the output `<input="radio" name="Animal" value="cat">cat <br><input="radio" name="Animal" value="dog">dog <br><input="radio" name="Animal" value="sheep">sheep <br><input="radio" name="Animal" value="moose">moose <br>`. What is the problem? (aside from the lack of `<label>` elements)

Comment: There is no radio button to select when I run the file. It only outputs the text not a radio button then the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is small error on the echo statement. HTML radio button should read 
 but your output statement reads  instead.

Hence you should change

```
echo "<input=\"radio\" name=\"Animal\" value=\"{$radioButtonArray[$x]}\">{$radioButtonArray[$x]} <br>";
```

To

```
echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Animal\" value=\"{$radioButtonArray[$x]}\">{$radioButtonArray[$x]} <br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Animal\" value=\"{$radioButtonArray[$x]}\">{$radioButtonArray[$x]} <br>";
```

You are not specifying the input type.

Answer (score 0):

`input=\"radio\"` should be `input type=\"radio\"`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `input type="radio"` not `input="radio"`